# Swift UI Animate changing width not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: from simulator]

I am trying to use animate to change the width from original to 0.

```
self.imageView.bounds.size.width = self.imageViewW
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {self.imageView.bounds.size.width = 0}, completion: {nil})
```

However, when I run it, the image immediately expands and then shrinks back to the original size. I have no idea why. Please help if you have any ideas. Thanks

Comment: what is the image width before animation ?

Comment: image width is a positive value set with constraints

Comment: so animate constraint then ... instead of frame ...

Comment: I don't have a width constraint, only aspect ratio with height, but is it bad to animate the bounds if there are constraints?

Comment: yes ... aspect Ratio is related to width sir ...

Comment: hm doesn't do any animation when I change the aspect ratio's constant, and multiplier I can't change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213454/discussion-between-jawadali-and-theboneman14).

Answer (score 0):

make sure the clipsToBounds is true, and the contentMode is what you want